# How prove this $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{1}{|x-y|}}+\frac{i}{4}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{k}{2}}-\frac{C}{2\pi}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions

let 
$$J_{0}(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{2p}$$

and
$$Y_{0}(x)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}J_{0}(x)\left(\ln{\dfrac{x}{2}}+C\right)-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p(x/2)^{2p}}{(p!)^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}\dfrac{1}{k}\right)$$
and 
$$H^{(1)}_{n}=J_{n}+iY_{n}$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$
define
$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{i}{4}H^{(1)}_{0}(k|x-y|),x\neq y$$

show that:

> $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\ln{\dfrac{1}{|x-y|}}+\dfrac{i}{4}-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\ln{\dfrac{k}{2}}-\dfrac{C}{2\pi}+O\left(|x-y|^2\ln{\dfrac{1}{|x-y|}}\right)$$
>   For $|x-y|\to 0$,where $C$ is Euler's constant,

My  try: since
$$J_{0}(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{2p}$$
$$Y_{0}(x)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}J_{0}(x)\left(\ln{\dfrac{x}{2}}+C\right)-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p(x/2)^{2p}}{(p!)^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}\dfrac{1}{k}\right)$$
then
\begin{align*}
&H^{(1)}_{0}(x)=J_{0}(x)+iY_{0}(x)\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}(\dfrac{x}{2})^{2p}\left(\dfrac{2i}{\pi}\ln{\dfrac{x}{2}}+1\right)+\dfrac{2i}{\pi}\left(C\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}(\dfrac{x}{2})^{2p}-\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{(-1)^p}{(p!)^2}(\dfrac{x}{2})^{2p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

then I find this sum,Thank you

Comment: Is $Y_0$ even defined? It seems that second sum where the top index is $n-1$ results in a sum from $m=0 $ to $m=-1$, which makes no sense.

Comment: Oh,That's right,Thank you

Comment: Just consider the behavior of $H^{(1)}$ around $0$.

Comment: Hello,@i707107,can you post your solution,I fell this sum I can't follow this work,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Lemma**)
$H_0^{(1)}(x) = 1+ \frac{2i}{\pi}\left(\ln\frac{x}{2}+C\right)+O(x^2\ln{|x|})$.

The proof of this is just collecting constant terms and natural logarithms, everything else can be consumed in the error term.

The rest of the argument is just multiplying $i/4$ and plugging in $k|x-y|$ in the above lemma.

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much! I know.+1